# How to make my scraper click an HTML button on a website (preferably) using requests

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, python-requests, python-requests-html

I am creating a website scraper and have so far successfully automated logging on and navigating the website with the use of requests alone. But the next tasks the scraper needs to complete is to click a button to open a form within the website. this is what the button looks like as the web element (I've turned some text into gobbledygook):

```
<button class="btn btn-link">search criteria: 'hd eijfwor ok' (jeiofij ji wdpojq), from: 2020-10-01, to: 2020-12-31</button>
```

what action does my code have to perform to click this button? Preferably this would only require requests , but im open to all other options.

cheers.

Comment: Requests isn't capable of interacting with web pages it just downloads the source. To interact with a page you need to use something like Selenium

Comment: Use your browser's developer tools to see what data the page posts when you click the button and the URL it posts to then try to replicate that using requests.

Comment: @JustinEzequiel Can you point me to someplace I can read up on this in detail .like with example?..I tried this on my own ..but wasn't able to find (after checking breakpoints mouse click) in the developer options. Thanks

Comment: @JustinEzequiel i have tried to do this. when the button is pressed, `<div id="snackbar"></div>` turns into   `<div id="snackbar" aria-hidden="true"></div>`